# How to set GitLab runner on k8s, executor Docker not Kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, gitlab, kubernetes-helm, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm trying to set GitLab runner on k8s and I want to change the default executor "Kubernetes to Docker".
**I did't find a single article on the internet. What is wrong??**

I installed GitLab runner via [HelmChart](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/kubernetes.html)

While installing via helm I used config [values.yaml](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/charts/gitlab-runner/blob/main/values.yaml?_gl=1%2A1qzi4f7%2A_ga%2AMTM0NzQ1MzIxOS4xNjY1NTYyMjAy%2A_ga_ENFH3X7M5Y%2AMTY2ODQwMDU1OS42LjAuMTY2ODQwMDU1OS4wLjAuMA..)

I tried to change:.
`executor: kubernetes` to `executor: docker` and

```
 config: |
    [[runners]]
      [runners.docker]
        namespace = "{{.Release.Namespace}}"
        image = "docker"
```

in values.yaml but not helped

Error: [image]

**I don't know where to change in values.yaml to configure Docker executor**

Successfully running on by default Kuberenetes Executor.

[image]